# How to make a wso2 enterprise integrator custom mediator with dependencies

Tags: mediator, wso2-enterprise-integrator

When I make a custom mediator in wso2 enterprise integrator, I compile it without dependencies (in maven), because if I do with that, then wso2 not run, because that dependencies included, break wso2.

I'd like to make a wso2 mediator whith its own dependencies. How can I do It?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create your mediator as osgi bundle (don't let ei convert it to osgi because then it will bind the wrong classes). I've had a similar issue where I had to use another version of javax.xml.crypto in my mediator. I therefor modified the pom.xml like this and build the mediator.

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>smybolicName</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Bundle-Name>bundleName</Bundle-Name>
                    <Import-Package>
                        !javax.xml.crypto.*; version="1.4.2.patched",
                        org.apache.xml.security;version="0.0.0",
                        *
                    </Import-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: And where I put the jar, in dropins path?

Comment: Yes, I used esb 4.8.1 and put it into <ESB_HOME>\repository\components\dropins